# How to properly update JIRA SVN plugin config after first initialization?

Tags: svn, plugins, config, jira

After configuring 2 repos in subversion-jira-plugin.properties file according to instructions provided in readme file I copied 3 jar files to lib folder and properties file to class folder and restarted jira service. Then I made few commits containing issues IDs to the repos I declared in subversion-jira-plugin file. On the project main screen on the Subversion Commits  tab I can see all commits I made – everything works.

However  If I add another repository in config file this repo seems to be ignored – commits made to third repo doesn’t appear on Subversion Commit tab.

I suppose that content of the subversion-jira-plugin.properties file has been cached somewhere because in the export file (C:\Program Files (x86)\Atlassian\Application Data\JIRA\export\.zip\entites.xml)  there are only entries “OSPropertyString” containing values of users, paths, names etc. of the 2 repositories that were first created, nothing about third repository.

I have restarted jira service and cleared folder {$jira's_index_dir}/plugins/atlassian-subversion-revisions/ few times with no luck. I have set Subversion Revision Indexing Service delay time to 3 minutes.

My config file:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Atlassian\JIRA\atlassian-jira\WEB-INF\classes\subversion-jira-plugin.properties:

```
svn.root=http://localhost:8080/svn/test1/trunk
svn.root.1=http://localhost:8080/svn/test2/trunk
#added after first initialization
svn.root.2=http://localhost:8080/svn/test3/trunk
svn.display.name=Test1 Repository
svn.display.name.1=Test2 Repository

#added after first initialization
svn.display.name.2=Repo3
# Subversion username same for all repos
svn.username=<user>
svn.password=<mypass>
…
```

Probably I am missing something, so my question is:

How to properly update svn plugin config after first initialization? 
JIRA 4.4 
SVN plugin 0.10.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've received the answer at
[how-to-properly-update-svn-plugin-config-after-first-initialization](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/34907/how-to-properly-update-svn-plugin-config-after-first-initialization-jira-4-4-svn-plugin-0-10-7/34913)

> "The way it works is confusing... the properties file appears to update the list of repos only if they don't already exist (in the database).
>
> Instead of adding repos through the properties file, which is hard to maintain as you need >to bounce jira every time, add them through the UI. Admin -> Repositories." - Jamie Echlin

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the database, you can get the plugin to read all values from the configuration file by stopping Jira, deleting the previous values, and restarting. The values you define in the config file will be imported as new values.

You can find the setting entry values here:

```
SELECT *
FROM [jiradb].[jiraschema].[propertyentry]
WHERE ENTITY_NAME='jira.plugins.subversion.repo';
```

And the string entries themselves:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [jiradb].[jiraschema].[propertystring]
WHERE ID IN(
    SELECT ID
    FROM [jiradb].[jiraschema].[propertyentry]
    WHERE ENTITY_NAME='jira.plugins.subversion.repo'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have studied the [documentation to Subversion JIRA Plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/SVN/Subversion+JIRA+plugin) and found there the following sentence:

> If you make any configuration changes, please delete the $INDEXDIR/plugins/atlassian-subversion-revisions directory and restart JIRA to make the change take effect.

So perhaps you just forgot that.